# Webpack 4 and Uglify Plugin (TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, yarnpkg, webpack-plugin

I'm having problems with Webpack 4 on a Linux machine. The build works fine in dev mode, but fail in production. It also seems to be working on a windows machine. I did try do downgrade webpack to an older version and nothing.

Nodejs:
v10.2.1

```
 *TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined* at node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/index.js:59
        this.workers = workers === true ? _os2.default.cpus().length - 1 : Math.min(Number(workers) || 0, _os2.default.cpus().length - 1);
```

packge.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.5.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "global": "^4.3.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.1",
    "npm": "^6.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "ts-loader": "^4.4.2",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.0.0-beta.2",
    "webpack": "^4.15.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    devtool: 'source-map',
     mode: 'production',
     module: {
             rules: [{
                 test: /\.tsx?$/,
                 use: 'ts-loader',
                 exclude: /node_modules/
             },
             {
                 test: /\.scss$/,
                 use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                 exclude: /node_modules/
             }
            ],
         },
    resolve: {
             extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js','.css','.scss']
         },
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin()
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'main.js'
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give more detail like webpack config file, package.json, or anything relevant?

Comment: just added webpack.config.js and packge.json

Comment: Your version of `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` is a year old. It may be because of that. See if `npm install -S uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@latest` fixes the problem.

Comment: By the way, is there a reason why `npm` is in your dependencies?

Comment: @Aankhen nothing. I don't think it has something to do with the version.

Comment: Okay. Is your production build on the same machine but with a different `NODE_ENV` (or other variables) or is it on a different machine?

Comment: @Aankhen It's on a different machine (Linux server)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174646/discussion-between-aankhen-and-yacine-benzmane).

Comment: Delete you `node_modules` folder, then do a fresh `npm i`. By the looks of it you have tried to run with packages that were installed for a machine running MacOS.

Comment: @connexo deleted the `node_modules` and run `yarn` but still get the same problem.

Comment: Because this seems to be a very involved issue, you should probably make a minimal project on github which has the bare minimum code to reproduce the problem on your machine. This will help others diagnose the issue.

Comment: @damanptyltd I did try using a boilerplate project but kept getting the same error in prod. I even disabled uglify from my project and the build still failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting `mode` to `production` in Webpack v4 should do enough optimisations, so there's no need to specifically require the Uglify plugin. Try remove `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` and there's also no need for passing the `-p` flag for the `build` script.

If you want to customise the Uglify plugin, you can also do so in Webpack's `optimization` config, see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({ /* your config */ })
    ]
  }
};
```

Finally, I have a basic webpack v4 starter boilerplate with all the latest ecosystem on Github, [take a look](https://github.com/bodaz/webpack-4-react) and see if it will help you or not

Comment: Removing uglifyjs-webpack-plugin do not help, I think uglifyjs is used by default by webpack in prod mode.

Comment: I did still get the same issue, I think it something with node.

Comment: okay then the issue might be somewhere else then, cus the boilerplate works on my machine and my colleagues'