# webpack 4 disable uglifyjs-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs, webpack-4, webpack-plugin

I have had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243247/webpack-4-and-uglify-plugin-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefin) problem for the last 2 days. So I decided to completely disable `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` from webpack build process. I was not able to find anything on webpack 4.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
module.exports = {
    optimization:{
        minimize: false, // <---- disables uglify.
        // minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()] if you want to customize it.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are managing single `webpack.config.js` and using `package.json npmscripts` based on environment. You can use this approach as well.

You can do something like this: creating a defaultplugins array and check the environment, if environment is prod, the push to array otherwise use defaultplugins. as shown in example:

**`package.json`**

```
"config-prod": "webpack --env.NODE_ENV=prod --parallel build-webpack",
"build-prod": "npm run config-prod"
```

**`webpack.config.js`** Added only relevant sections, so that it's easy to read

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
const UglifyJSPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const webpackUtilities = require("./webpack.utilities");

module.exports = (env) => {
  var defaultplugins = [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
       ///// section deleted
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      ///// section deleted
    }),
  ];

  return {
    mode: env.NODE_ENV == "prod" ? "production" : "development",
    devtool: env.NODE_ENV == "prod" ? "" : "source-map";,
    entry: {
      ///// section deleted
    },
    output: {
         ///// section deleted
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          ///// section deleted
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins:
      env.NODE_ENV == "prod"
        ? [...defaultplugins, new UglifyJSPlugin()]
        : [...defaultplugins],
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".scss", ".css"],
    },
  };
};
```