# Webpack: how to disable minimizer in production

Tags: webpack

I would like to disable Webpacks [optimization.minimize](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationminimize).

The example in the docs

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  },
};
```

works for me only with `mode: development`.

So how to achiev that?

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51264532/10944219), but it does not respect `mode: production`.